# Python array creation with shape

Tags: python, shapes, diagonal

```
a = np.diag(np.array([2,3,4,5,6]),k=-1)
```

For the above code, I want to know how to change it for shaping the 6*6 matrix into 6*5 matrix with the first line is filled with 0 and the following lines with 2,3,4,5,6 to be diagonal? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to know.
In your code if k>0 
then the resultant matrix will have k extra columns,if k=2 then,
output will be :

```
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And if k<0 then it will have the k extra rows , for example if k=-1
then:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0]])
```

and if k=0 then :

```
array([[2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 6]])
```

I think you want to create a matrix of 5*5 and then want too add a row. Then you can do it using this

```
a=a.tolist()
```

Now a is 2d list and you can insert the row wherever you want.
Do this for your result.

```
a.insert(0,[0,0,0,0,0])
```